# Ajax only displays the response text of last file element of the array

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, onclick

Using Ajax, I want to display the response text of a certain file when clicking its corresponding tab; for example, when clicking the "Box 1" tab, it must display the response text of `box1.html`, "Box 2" for `box2.html`, and "Box 3" for `box3.html` - (the box files are located inside the `ajax` folder). The issue is, all the three tabs displays only the response text of `box3.html`. When I open the console to look for errors, there was none.

HTML

```
<section>
    <!-- TABS -->
    <div>
        <button>Box 1</button>
        <button>Box 2</button>
        <button>Box 3</button>
    </div>


    <!-- ResponseText container -->
    <div id="response-text"></div>
</section>
```

JavaScript

```
function query(selector) {
    return Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(selector));
}

query('button').forEach(function(btn) {
    btn.onclick = function() {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var files = ['box1', 'box2', 'box3'];

        for(var f=0; f<files.length; f++) {
            var result = files[f];
            xhr.open('POST', 'ajax/'+result+'.html', true);
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                    document.querySelector('#response-text').textContent = xhr.responseText;
                }
            }
            xhr.send();
        }
    }
});
```

Is my style of pushing elements into arrays improper?
I would appreciate so much the corrections, improvements, and tips that you would suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably overwriting the div, with command
document.querySelector( '# response-text') textContent = xhr.responseText.;
switch to append and see if it works correctly.
document.querySelector( '# response-text') append( xhr.responseText);